# Simulating a Wave Pulse

Tags: plotting, manipulate, simulation

How to construct a code that superimpose `n=10` one dimensional sinuisodal waves. each with an angular frequency `ωi(*i is subscript*)` and wave number `ki` to form a wave pulse.Each angular frequency `ωi` and wave number `ki`differs slightly from the previous one only by a small fraction, namely. `Δω=|ωi+1-ωi|<<ωi` `Δk=|ki+1-ki|<<ki`

i plan to `Manipulate[]` the simulation for n=50 waves. i would like to see the difference in the wavepulse composed of n=50 and n=10 waves.
this is what have been construct so far.

```
A1 = 1; k1 = 4; ω = 2; A2 = 5; ω2 = 10; k2 = 3
y1[x_, t_] := A1*Sin[k1*x - ω*t];
y2[x_, t_] := (A2*Sin[k2*x - ω2*t]);
Plot[{y1[x, t = 0.5], y2[x, t = 0.5]}, {x, -10, 10}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{y1[x, t = n] + y2[x, t = n]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {n, 0, 100, 0.25}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angularrate = Range[10];
amplitude = RandomReal[{.1, 1}, 10];
Animate[Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[amplitude[[i]] Sin[angularrate[[i]] t - x], {i, 10}], 
  {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Table[Hue[j/10], {j, 10}],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True], 
  {t, 0, 10},
  AnimationRate -> .1]
```